# Razor, output values from comma separated list

Tags: razor

New to razor syntax. I have a comma separated list, `@item.profilePosition` that appears like this: item1,item2,item3.

I need to output the list in a class like this `class="item1 item2 item3`. Would I need to create an array with split?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@string.Join(" ", item.profilePosition.Split(','))
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `@item.profilePosition` is a string, could you just replace the commas with spaces?

```
class="@item.profilePosition.Replace(",", " ")"
```